# The Diagram explanation of the LSTM Network

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am working with LSTM for my time series forecasting problem. I have the following network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units_size=300, activation=activation, input_shape=(20, 1)))
model.add(Dense(20))
```

My forecasting problem is to forecast the next 20 time steps looking back the last 20 time steps. So, for each iteration, I have an input shape like (x_t-20...x_t) and forecast the next (x_t+1...x_t+20). For the hidden layer, I use 300 hidden units.

As LSTM is different than the simple feed-forward neural network, I cannot understand how those 300 hidden units used for the LSTM cells and how the output comes out. Are there 20 LSTM cells and 300 units for each cell? How is the output generated from these cells? As I describe above, I have 20 time steps to predict and are these all steps generated from the last LSTM cels? I have no idea. Can some generally give a diagram example of this kind of network structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding these questions,

*I cannot understand how those 300 hidden units used for the LSTM cells and how the output comes out. Are there 20 LSTM cells and 300 units for each cell? How is the output generated from these cells?*

It is simpler to consider the LSTM layer you have defined as a single block. This diagram is heavily borrowed from Francois Chollet's Deep Learning with Python book:

[image]

In your model, input shape is defined as (20,1), so you have 20 time-steps of size 1. For a moment, consider that the output Dense layer is not present.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(300, input_shape=(20,1)))
model.summary()
```

lstm_7 (LSTM)                (None, 300)               362400

The output shape of the LSTM layer is 300 which means the output is of size 300.

```
output = model.predict(np.zeros((1, 20, 1)))
print(output.shape)
```

(1, 300)

**input (1,20,1)** => batch size = 1, time-steps = 20, input-feature-size = 1.

**output (1, 300)**      => batch size = 1, output-feature-size = 300

Keras recurrently ran the LSTM for 20 time-steps and generated an output of size (300). In the diagram above, this is *Output t+19*.

Now, if you add the Dense layer after LSTM, the output will be of size 20 which is straightforward.

Comment: as I understand from the figure for each input there is an output. But in my case, there is no output in the first 19 LSTM cell, and all 300 output comes out from the last 20th LSTM cell.  Am I right on this understanding?

Comment: Yes, only the final output since return_sequences=False.

Answer (score 1):

To understand LSTMs, I'd recommend first spending a few minutes to understand 'plain vanilla' RNNs, as LSTMs are just a more complex version of that. I'll try to describe what's happening in your network if it was a basic RNN.

You are training a single set of weights that are repeatedly used for each time step (`t-20,...,t`).  The first weight (let's say `W1`) is for inputs. One by one, each of `x_t-20,...,x_t` is multiplied by `W1`, then a non-linear activation function is applied - same as any NN forward pass.

The difference with RNNs is the presence of a separate 'state' (note: not a trained weight), that can start off random or zero, and carries information about your sequence across time steps. There's another weight for the state (`W2`).  So starting at the first time step `t-20`, the initial state is multiplied by `W2` and an activation function applied.

So at timestep `t-20` we have the output from `W1` (on inputs) and `W2` (on state).  We can combine these outputs at each timestep, and use it to generate the state to pass to the next timestep, i.e. `t-19`. Because the state has to be calculated at each timestep and passed to the next, these calculations have to happen sequentially starting from t-20.  To generate our desired output, we can take each output state across all timesteps - or only take the output at the final timestep. As `return_sequences=False` by default in Keras, you are only using the output at the final timestep, which then goes into your dense layer.

The weights `W1` and `W2` need to have one dimension equal to the dimensions of each timestep input `x_t-20...` for matrix multiplication to work.  This dimension is 1 in your case, as each of the 20 inputs are a 1d vector (or number), which is multiplied by `W1`. However, we're free to set the second dimension of the weights as we please - 300 in your case.  So `W1` is of size 1x300, and is multiplied 20 times, once for each timestep.

[This lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQxm3Upr3_I) will take you through the basic flow diagram of RNNs that I described above, all the way to more advanced stuff which you can skip.  [This is a famous explanation of LSTMs](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) if you want to make the leap from basic RNNs to LSTMs, which you may not need to do - there are just more complicated weights and states.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have not used return_sequence=True here. So it is default false. And in this case, As I understand I get all 300 output from the final time step. And for 300 units connected to the last 20 output in a fully connected way.  Am I right? and as I understand if I put return_sequence=True, in this case, I should get the output from the LSTM for each input time step. Does It mean I will get 300 units from each LSTM cell?